# Can exchange interaction exist between electron and muon?

Tags: condensed-matter, standard-model, leptons, exchange-interaction

I'm studying about the exchange interaction and it's quite confusing.

Why does it happens between same kinds of particle?

How about electron and muon? Or one particle and another one which has all the same properties except mass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an exchange-like interaction between the proton and the neutron. We usually call this "isospin symmetry," for "isotopic spin," because it is a symmetry in the approximation where we can neglect the proton-neutron mass difference and also neglect the electric charge difference. Neglecting electric charge is possible only because electromagnetism is overwhelmed by the strong interaction.

We can extend the "isospin" quantum number to the up- and down-flavored quarks.  But we cannot extend isospin symmetry in any meaningful way to the strange quark, which is much heavier than either of the first-generation quarks.  Likewise there is no isospin-like symmetry between the charm and strange quarks, whose masses are drastically different.

You ask specifically about the electron and muon, which do not participate in the strong interaction, and whose masses are different by a factor of approximately 200.  At experimentally-accessible energies, that mass difference is cannot be neglected, and there is no analog of the particle-exchange symmetry between the electron and the muon.

Comment: In atoms and molecules electron exchange is often the main contributor to singlet triplet splitting. Is any similar splitting observed in the proton-deuteron context? Such a system should have antisymmetry under the exchange of identical quarks. I am trying to connect your answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Yes. The deuteron ground state famously includes the isospin part of the wavefunction in the overall antisymmetry. Total isospin is a pretty good quantum number in nuclei whose stable isotopes have $N≈Z$, which is the regime where charge is negligible to the nuclear dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exchange interaction between an electron and a muon. These are non-identical particles and a wave function containing electrons and muons is not (anti-)symmetrised under electron-muon exchange.